# How to calculate and display marker on clicked place in image?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have code written in .cshtml

The div below contains a map in jpg form. I wrote a JS code for this that calculates the click location on this map and then the HTML + C# code places a marker on the clicked location.

Unfortunately it doesn't work properly. It shows the place I clicked but it is moved to the right. On the phone, it displays the marker in a completely different place (off the map or in the wrong place on the map)

```
                <div class="image-container">
                    <div class="image-wrapper" id="imageWrapper">
                        <img id="mapImage" src="/assets/map.jpg" alt="Map" style="position: relative !important; width: 100% !important; height: auto !important;">
                        <div id="markers-container">
                            @foreach (var asset in Model.AssetsList)
                            {
                                var ImageWidth = 1840;
                                var ImageHeight = 1130;
                                <div class="marker" style="left: @(asset.PosX)%; top: @(asset.PosY)%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); position: absolute;">
                                    <img src="@Model.AssetTypesList.Where(a => a.Id == asset.AssetTypeId).FirstOrDefault()?.ImageUrl" alt="@asset.BoatName" style="width: 25%; height: auto;" />
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <button id="image-change-button">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-right-left "></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
```

JS:

```
 function selectMarker(assetTypeId) {
        selectedMarkerId = assetTypeId;
        closePopup();

        document.getElementById("imageWrapper").style.cursor = "crosshair";

        var mapImage = document.getElementById("mapImage");
        mapImage.addEventListener("click", function (event) {

            var offsetX = event.offsetX;
            var offsetY = event.offsetY;

            var image = new Image();
            image.src = mapImage.src;
            var imageWidth = mapImage.width;
            var imageHeight = mapImage.height;


            // positions in percents
            posX = (offsetX / imageWidth) * 100;
            posY = (offsetY / imageHeight) * 100;

            openAddAssetPopup();

            mapImage.style.cursor = "default";
        }, { once: true });
    }
```

Can someone help me what I need to change in the JS or C# / HTML code so that it picks up the exact place where I clicked IN the image. And then let the marker be generated in exactly the same place where you clicked (on the image, of course, not on the page), regardless of how the page is displayed (on mobile it has a different arrangement)

Comment: Two things 1) You need to cast imageWidth to a float or double so you do no get an integer divide. 2) Where is the origin of the image?  Usually it is in the upper left with positive x to the right and positive y going down.  Offset must be relative to the origin of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use wrong image width and height when calculating the click position.

Try to get sizes with:

```
var mapImage = document.getElementById("mapImage");
var imageWidth = mapImage.naturalWidth;
var imageHeight = mapImage.naturalHeight;
```